# Custom GtkFileChooserWidget

Tags: c++, gtk

I have some troubles with bulding custom GtkFileChooserDialog.
How can I set custom icons to popup dialogs (for example, this dialog popups, when I click to CD-ROM with not insterted CD) and set custom name to "Name", "Modified", "Size" labels?
Thanks!

P.S. Please, sorry for my English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filenames and modified date is displayed in a treeview inside GtkFileChooserDialog.

I dont think there is a way to get the treeview from the GtkFileChooserDialog.
If you manage to get the treeview. You can change the column names of the treeview.
Refer Programming in GTK+ by andrew krauss, building your own custom widgets module.
You might get some help.

This is the structure of GtkFileChooserDialog,

```
struct GtkFileChooserDialog 
{
  GtkDialog parent_instance;
  GtkFileChooserDialogPrivate *priv;
};

/* GtkFileChooserDialog private */
struct _GtkFileChooserDialogPrivate
{
  GtkWidget *widget;
  char *file_system;
  /* for use with GtkFileChooserEmbed */
  gboolean response_requested;
};
```

There is no specific API in GTK to get the treeview from GtkFileChooserDialog.
Treeview is not part of this structure, It is internal and not available for programmer to access.

If this doesnt work then, try writing your own custom widget. or design your own filechooser dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand clearly, what is your question.
This is what i understood from your question, you want to change the button names in the file chooser dialog.

You can specify the names of the buttons while creating the file choose dialog.

GtkWidget *dialog;

dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",
                                      parent_window,
                                      "Buttonname 1",
                                      "Buttonname 2",
                                      "Buttonname 3",
                                      NULL);

Buttonname 1, 2 ,3 are the names of your custom buttons.

Comment: Yes, I know this feature. I try to say about other thing: when you open GtkFileChooserDialog window, you can see right window with "Name", "Modified" and "Size" file sorting. How can I modify their names (for example "Name" -> "Names", "Modified" -> "Last modify" e.t.c.)? Also I don't know how modify icons of popup message dialogs in GtkFileChooserDialog...

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. `Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid input string`